# Pyodbc Connections

Tags: windows, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc & sql alchemy for windows to establish a database connection to SQL Server.  I have a number of methods that make lightweight reads from the database.  Within each, I establish a new connection, and close the connection when the query is complete.  These methods are called over loops and execute many times throughout program execution.

My question is whether is beneficial to pass the same connection object to a number of different methods, thus keeping it open, and close it at the end of the program, or to continue to create a new connection and close it within each.  Are there any performance impacts or consequences to one vs the other?

Comment: You could work up some simple test code to see if it makes a significant difference. It may not, because the Windows ODBC subsystem enables connection pooling by default for the SQL Server ODBC driver, so when you open a "new" connection you may actually be getting your old connection back from the pool.

Comment: @GordThompson very insightful, thank you, Gord